# IMU sensor Vectornav VN100 driver doesn't post any INS messages

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, c++, imu

I've already posted the same question on the **GitHub page** of the **VectorNAV** driver: github.com/dawonn/vectornav/issues/128 But no luck, noone gets back to me, looks like the branch isn't in much support right now.

My system is **Ubuntu 18.04, ROS1 Melodic** (trying to get INS messages on x86 computer now, but final goal is Nvidia TX2, which is ARM computer if it matters)

First, I wanted to make my own node, using **Python 3**, because **VectorNAV** provides **Python 3.4+** libraries and they are super easy to use for me. But, as I mentioned above, my system is using **ROS1** and it has **Python 2.7** as a default. I know, that it is possible to change default version for the **ROS1** to **Python 3x**, but I have a lot of nodes, which were built based on **Python 2.7** libraries.

I've asked **VectorNAV** support do they have **Python 2** libraries, they answered negative and redirected me to the **ROS1** VectorNAV driver which is already exists: github.com/dawonn/vectornav Which is based on **C++** script. After that I've downloaded this driver, built it in my **catkin space** and tried to use.

The problem is that I can't see the messages with **"roll" "pitch"** and **"yaw"** angles information (in degrees, as i says in **msg/Ins.msg file**)

My device is **VN100** according to this I've modified **/launch/vectornav.launch** file to:
[image: vectornav.launch]

After running the commands:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and

```
roscore
```

and after that

```
roslaunch vectornav vectornav.launch
```

Using `rostopic list` I can see the following topics:

```
~/catkin_ws$ rostopic list
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/vectornav/GPS
/vectornav/IMU
/vectornav/INS
/vectornav/Mag
/vectornav/Odom
/vectornav/Pres
/vectornav/Temp
```

and most of them works and shows me the messages: IMU for example:

[image]

or temperature:

[image]

But the only one I need, with **pitch, roll** and **yaw** information, as I understand, should be in `/vectornav/INS` topic

and when I run the command:

```
rostopic echo /vectornav/INS
```

it just give me nothing:

[image]

I've found one problem, that **Ins.msg** which you can see in the package:

[image]

weren't build at first, but now I've modified the **package.xml** and **CMakeLists.txt** and using command

```
rosmsg list show
```

I can see `vectornav` messages

which should contain **yaw, roll** and **pitch** information:

[image]

But, again, as I mention above, command

```
rostopic echo /vectornav/Ins
```

gives me nothing:

[image]

Looks like the only things which works (publishing working) are the standard std messages, such as **/sensor_msg/temperature** or **/std_msg/IMU**

[image]

And logically to think that the problem with building the custom messages.. But I see now that they were succesfully built as I showed above.

Anyone has any advise? Or maybe someone faced with the similar problem using VectorNAV ***VN100***?

Best, Andrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for my particular problem.

I just **commented "if" condition** for the **INS** publishing part of the C++ script, see the screenshot below.

[image]

*talking about ROS [driver for VectorNAV](https://github.com/dawonn/vectornav)

In the file **/vectornav/src/main.cpp** I've commented **lines 814-816 and 820**

So, basically, I just **removed an if condition** for the INS part.
Seems like for some reason it doesn't get "True" and the publishing INS part of the code just skipped.

I didn't try it before, because it is absolutely the same condition as for **IMU** data, or **temperature** data.
Maybe because these are (IMU and temperature) default ROS messages, publishing IMU/temperature data didn't have the same problem as INS publishing (which is processed data I believe, so it is not raw data, like IMU for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked using the control center sw if the VN is actually publishing INS messages? Then you should also check which ports are selected for output and the rate limits. When having everything maxed out the bandwidth of the serial connection is not enough so you have to choose or throttle some frequencies.
If its publishing those topics then in your program you need to check what groups of topics are you decoding and if you are packing them accordingly.